# What's the difference between Rendering pipeline and compute shader?

Tags: shaders, directx, rendering

What's the difference between rendering pipeline - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476882.aspx and compute shader - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476331.aspx ?

Comment: You've asked a number of questions that are not well fit for this site. I suggest you take your questions to a site that's more open to discussion and other questions that aren't fit for this site. Try gamedev.net or reddit.com/r/gamedev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic difference is simple: The standard Rendering pipeline configures the GPU so it processes data as vertices, then rasterizes them into points/lines/triangles, and then processes the result as pixels which are written into a buffer using optional blending.

A DirectCompute shader just takes data from a buffer and then process them in parallel to produce data in another buffer. The data could be visual, it could result in something that could be reused in the standard Rendering pipeline, or it could just be data that is used in some custom way that has not at all to do with graphics rendering.